# Mac Connect to Server doesn't show login screen:

Tags: mac, passwords, network-shares, connection, login

Using Connect TO Server function, I entered credentials once, incorrectly, now I use connect to server and it doesn't show me the login screen but goes ahead and tries to mount the share ...

Anyway of deleting the old creds or force the login screen to populate?

thx

10.8.3 OSX

Answer (score 2):

First disconnect from the server. Then, in the Finder, navigate to Go > Utilities > Keychain Access and finding the keychain related to that server under "login." Delete it, quit out, and try connecting again.

Comment: Thanks... I have deleted the Key chain on user level and system level multiple times.

Comment: Are you sure it's in the *login* keychain? In my experience, those passwords are in the *system* keychain. @user242653, for me finding the credentials in the *system* keychain worked, but I've not tested recently. Also, what does *"on user level and system level"* mean? When referring to *login* and *system*, I mean the options in Keychain's sidebar; hit Command+K (menu View » Show Keychains) if you don't see that sidebar.